# Regex -replace PowerShell inside a bat cut fullpath

Tags: powershell, replace, diacritics

I am trying to delete from a .txt file some paths like :

```
Complete name                            : Z:\Vidéos\Japan Trip\DayXX.mkv
```

My goal is to have only :

```
Complete name                            : DayXX.mkv
```

I found here this code :

```
setlocal
set $source="%~f1-Temp\%Name%.txt"
set $Dest="%~f1-Temp\%Name%1.txt"

set "search=(?<=Complete name.*?: ).+/"
set "replace=New"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -c "(get-content '%$source%') | foreach-object {$_ -replace '%Search%', '%replace%'} | set-content '%$dest%'"') do echo %%a
endlocal
```

And after lots of tries, seems that the regex (?<=Complete name.*?: ).+ should work, but no.

My problems are : \ and french letter like é à ù.

Do you have any idea for me ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your mixture of CMD/Batch and Powershell is quite error prone. Why not using pure Powershell? In a simple version something like this could be enough:

```
$Content = Get-Content -Path 'InputFile.txt'
$NewContent = 
$Content |
ForEach-Object {
    $_ -replace '(?<=Complete name\s+:\s+).+\\'
}
$NewContent | 
Out-File -FilePath 'InputFile.txt'
```

Comment: Hello Olaf, thanks ! It is a small part of a bash script, in fact. PS seems simpler than batch for dealing with replacement, therefore the mix of both

Comment: If I'm not wrong it's not **bash** it is **CMD** or **Batch** what's different. And Powershell is easily able to completely replace **CMD** scripts. And is more powerfull and easier to write ... you may consider to migrate the complete script to make it easier to maintain. ;-)

Comment: Yes, i will definitely do that, but as i start with CMD, it seems to work and i don't know if ever i will use it again... good enough for me :)